# How to build the multiplexed account address single string containing the account ID and memo ID?

Tags: transactions, accounts, wallets

I am working on adopting [CAP-0027](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/core/cap-0027.md) - First-class multiplexed accounts.

I assume that in the future, when one wishes to deposit to an exchange for example, the exchange will provide an address that is a union of the account ID and the memo ID in a **single** string. The wallet used by the user will have to take the long string from the user, break it to components and correctly build the transaction.

- Is this correct?
- How is the multiplexed account address single string built? Is it by simply concatenating the account ID and the memo ID? In which order? Any additional encoding instructions?
- Can you show examples of such strings with their components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.

The multiplexed account address is a 69 characters long string which is a result of the strkey encoding of the [`muxedAccount` XDR type](https://github.com/xdrpp/stellar-core/blob/dm/muxacct/src/xdr/Stellar-transaction.x#L11). The original ed25519PublicKey XDR encoding is 56 characters long.

The strkey encoding is currently in draft status: [SEP-0023](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0023.md). Sample address strings can be found [there](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0023.md#valid-test-cases):

#### Valid multiplexed account

- Strkey: `MAAAAAAAAAAAAAB7BQ2L7E5NBWMXDUCMZSIPOBKRDSBYVLMXGSSKF6YNPIB7Y77ITLVL6`
- Memo ID: `0`
- ed25519: `GA7QYNF7SOWQ3GLR2BGMZEHXAVIRZA4KVWLTJJFC7MGXUA74P7UJVSGZ`

#### Valid multiplexed account in which unsigned id exceeds maximum signed 64-bit integer

- Strkey: `MAAAAAAAAAAAAAB7BQ2L7E5NBWMXDUCMZSIPOBKRDSBYVLMXGSSKF6YNPIB7Y77ITLVL6`
- Memo ID: `9223372036854775808`
- ed25519: `GA7QYNF7SOWQ3GLR2BGMZEHXAVIRZA4KVWLTJJFC7MGXUA74P7UJVSGZ`